# Disable MySQL to convert string to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL statement where the where clause is written like:

```
WHERE 1=1
and airport_code = 'MDW'
```

The problem is that airport code should have been a numeric number. I would expect no values to be returned. Instead, it returned to me the airport codes equal to 0. This threw me on a wrong direction when I was trying to figure out other issues with the data.

Is it possible to turn this functionality off when I run my queries?

Comment: Your application layer logic is flaky. Anything that is not an integer should never reach the db layer. Fix the app layer. It's possible you are wide open to SQL Injection as well.

Comment: Just to be sure if i understand it correctly, the type of olumn `airport_code` is numeric, and you problem is that `airport_code = 'MDW'` finds the row for which `airport_code` is `0`

Comment: you did not provide **clear** or **any** data set and query. From what you've described - that is not true. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44aad1/2

Comment: @Alex If you insert a `0` in the table you'll see it actually finds the zero.

Comment: ok. I see now http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a0955/1

Comment: If you `airport_code` is numeric, how can `and airport_code = 'MDW'` run???  It should not.

Comment: @Eric because mysql (and other DBMS) to implicit conversions. [12.3 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: `and CAST(airport_code AS CHAR) = 'MDW'`